# Unexpected output for a class methods in Python

Tags: python, polymorphism, class-method

Which of the following correctly describe the complete output of executing the Python Polymorphic functions below? I got this question online which I think the output is unexpected. Primary class has object inside it, shouldnt it matter?  Also can we write classmethod inside a function as an argument?

```
class Primary(object):
    def show(self):
        print("Primary class is called")

class Secondary(Primary):
    def show(self):
        print("Secondary class is called")

def result(classmethod):
    classmethod.show()


primaryobj = Primary()
secondaryobj = Secondary()

result(primaryobj)
result(secondaryobj)
```

The output that I got is :

```
Primary class is called
Secondary class is called
```

Comment: `classmethod` is just an arbitrary name that happens to clash and shadow with the existing `classmethod` function. It's a bad name for that reason, and because those aren't methods being passed. What are you expecting the output to be though?

Comment: ok then why the object is being imported inside the Primary class/? @Carcigenicate

Comment: That's not an import. It's saying that `Primary` is a subclass of `object`, which is already implicitly the case in Python 3.

Comment: What do you mean by "which of the following"? There's no description following.

Comment: `result(primaryobj)` is equivalent to `primaryobj.show()`. `result(secondaryobj)` is equivalent to `secondaryobj.show()`. Why do you think the output is unexpected?

Comment: @Reactoo the classmethod argument is is an odd name.  what is being passed in to result is the constructed object primaryobj and then in the second call secondaryobj. as Barmar noted its the right output.

Comment: The author of that problem wrote a bad code. You don't need to specify 'object' as a base class. And the 'class is called' is an incorrect description. Also on the 'result()' function, 'result' is not a verb. And finally on the 'classmethod' argument, its name is very bad, because it's actually an object(instance).